# VBA return sum of range values from different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA in an excel sheet (lets call it wbA) to find the sum of the values in a range of cells in another workbook (lets call that wbB). I have tried using a custom made summing function

```
Function sumrange(rng As Range)

summ = 0
For Each cell In rng
summ = summ + cell.Value
Next
sumrange = summ

End Function
```

which i  execute in the wbA here

```
Sub test4()
Dim app As New Excel.Application

Dim book As Excel.Workbook
Set book = app.Workbooks.Add("...\wbB.xlsm")

With book.Worksheets("November2013")

a = sumrange(Range("B5:T9"))

End With
MsgBox a
End Sub
```

This returns the sum of the set range in wbA instead of wbB

i have also tried the worksheetfunction.sum option in the following formats

```
l = book.Worksheets("November2013").Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(B5:T9"))
```

and

```
With book.Worksheets("December2014")
p = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(B5:T9"))
End With
```

but both caluclate and return  the sum of the range from wbA instead of from wbB

How do i write the code to find sum of range in wbB 
Thanks

Comment: Birdsview: Change `Range("B5:T9")` to `.Range("B5:T9")` in  `a = sumrange(Range("B5:T9"))`

Comment: @SiddharthRout getting an "argument not optional" error

Comment: Which line? BTW are you running this from within excel?

Comment: changed 
a = sumrange(Range("B5:T9"))
to a = sumrange.Range("B5:T9"))

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes i am running it from the VBA window in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me with the change that I mentioned. This is what I tried

When you specify a range without fully qualifying it, it will always refer to active sheet. And `ActiveSheet` might not be the sheet that you expect it to be and hence fully qualify your objects.

```
Sub test4()
    Dim book As Workbook
    Dim a

    Set book = Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx")

    a = sumrange(book.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A4"))

    MsgBox a
End Sub

Function sumrange(rng As Range)
    summ = 0
    For Each cell In rng
    summ = summ + cell.Value
    Next
    sumrange = summ
End Function
```

I notice that you are using

```
Set book = app.Workbooks.Add("...\wbB.xlsm")
```

Use `.Open` Like I have done.

**EDIT**:

> @SiddharthRout yes i am running it from the VBA window in excel – user3041384 3 mins ago

In such a case, you don't need to define your excel application. Your code can be re-written as

```
Sub test4()
    Dim book As Workbook, a

    Set book = Workbooks.Open("...\wbB.xlsm")

    With book.Worksheets("November2013")
        a = sumrange(.Range("B5:T9"))
    End With

    MsgBox a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still looking for a one-line-solution:

```
Cells(10, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("data").Range(Worksheets("data").Cells(3, 35), Worksheets("data").Cells(131, 35)))
```

Just took it from my code, it addresses the range by cells, but you can easily use `RANGE("...")` instead of the `CELLS(,)` function).

The example line above writes the sum of worksheet "data" (`range("AI3:AI131")`) to A10 of current worksheet.